# How I can write a command in a terminal which is running a program and I open from a script

Tags: bash

I already know how to open a terminal in a bash with gnome-terminal and execute a program:

gnome-terminal -e ./OpenBTSCLI

But I also need that once open that program in the new terminal, write another command inside.

When a I tried to use echo, the message appear in the terminal where I run the bash.

I tried: gnome-terminal -e "bash -c './OpenBTSCLI && echo message'" that I find online but its not working, it only do the first part.

Anyone have an idea of how to resolve this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it does the second command as well, but the new terminal closes as soon as the command's finished, so you don't see it. I reversed the order of quotes and added a 1s sleep at the end to allow seeing the echo.

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "./OpenBTSCLI && echo message && sleep 1"'
```